# When will infinite loops, and recursive functions with no stop conditions, eventually stop?

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow, infinite-loop

I heard a myth saying that infinite loop or a recursive function with no stop condition will stop when "the stack overflows". Is it right?

For example :

```
void call()
{
call(); 
}
```

or

```
for(;;){;}
```

Will they really stop when the stack overflows?

**Update**: If it really stops, can I detect after how many recursive calls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It really depends on the choice of language.

In some languages, your infinite recursive function will halt with a stack overflow based on system- or language-dependent conditions.  The reason for this is that many implementations of function call and return allocate new space for each function call, and when space is exhausted the program will fail.  However, other languages (Scheme and various gcc optimization levels) will actually have this program run forever because they are smart enough to realize that they can reuse the space for each call.

In some languages, infinite loops will run forever.  Your program will just keep on running and never make progress.  In other languages, infinite loops are allowed to be optimized away by the compiler.  As an example, the C++ standard says that the compiler is allowed to assume that any loop will either terminate or make some globally-visible action, and so if the compiler sees the infinite loop it might just optimize the loop out of existence, so the loop actually does terminate.

In other words, it really depends.  There are no hard-and-fast answers to this question.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Your first example is a recursive method call - each invocation of `call` (in most languages and environments) will create a new stack frame, and eventually you'll run out of stack (you'll get a stack overflow condition).

Your second example involves no recursive method invocation - it's just a loop. No stack frames need to be created, and the stack won't overflow.

Give your examples a shot - the first example will cause a stack overflow faster than you may think. The second will make your fans spin really fast, but nothing will happen otherwise until you kill it.

Comment: Ok , so is there a method to detect after how many stack frame it will flows ?

Comment: Yes. Your computer holds a pointer to the top of the stack, and knows the maximum address of the stack. When it's asked to create a new stack frame, it checks that the new value of the stack pointer doesn't exceed that maximum address.

Comment: Regarding your edit - I suppose you could predict when the stack would overflow, by learning your process's stack size, computing/discovering the stack frame size for your particular platform and method signature, and doing some math. But why would you want to do this? You should not run into a stack overflow unless your program is faulty. There are some exceptions to that, but they're really rare. If your stack is growing that big, and it's not a program fault, look into tail-call optimization, as mentioned by icktoofay below.

Comment: The first one could likely be optimized with tail call optimizations, preventing a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which language you are using, the loop will end when maximum memory allocated or max execution time is reached. Some languages will detect infinite loop and stop it from running.

p.s. It is not a myth. You can actually try it.

Comment: How come some languages detect it and stop it from running, u have any examples ?

Comment: how about Objective-C in xCode ? it detects infinite loop in Analyze mode.

Answer (score 0):

"Update: If it really stops, can I detect after how many recursive calls?"

You most certainly can:

```
call(int n){
    print(n)
    call (n+1)
}
```

Then just call:

```
call(1)
```

When the stack overflow occurs, look at the last printed number. This was the number of method calls you had.

Hope this helps!
N.S.

Answer (score -1):

No matter the language, when I create a loop that is potentially infinite, I always build an "emergency exit" into it. I've done this in C#, VB.Net, VBA, JAVA, and just now for the first time in an IBM DB2 SQL function.

Since the concept is valid in any language, I'll present it in pseudocode, as follows:

```
Begin Procedure

Declare Variable safety_counter As Integer

Begin loop
    ...
    <body of code>
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- this is your normal exit
        Exit Loop
    End If
    ...
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
    If safety_counter >= 1000             <-- set to any value you wish
        Exit Loop                         <-- this is the emergency exit
    End If
End Loop
```

Some variations are as follows.

If the loop is simple, the two exit criteria might be written in the same If-Then:

```
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- normal exit
    Or safety_counter >= 1000             <-- emergency exit
        Exit Loop
    End If
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
```

An error value might be returned like this:

```
Begin Procedure

Declare Variable result_value   As Integer
Declare Variable safety_counter As Integer

Begin loop
    ...
    <body of code>
    If some_criteria = True Then          <-- this is your normal exit
        Set result_value = abc * xyz      <-- the value you seek          
        Exit Loop
    End If
    ...
    safety_counter = safety_counter + 1
    If safety_counter >= 1000             <-- set to any sufficient value
        Set result_value = (-123)         <-- indicate "infinite loop error"
        Exit Loop                         <-- this is the emergency exit
    End If
End Loop
Return result_value
```

There are many possible ways to do this, but the key is in safety_counter, and the way of monitoring it to trigger the emergency exit.